# How to mock an external module's function with Jest

Tags: jestjs

Can Jest's mocking handle functions from modules I didn't write?

[node-yelp-api-v3](https://github.com/joshuaslate/node-yelp-api) has `Yelp.searchBusiness(String)` but my attempts to use [Jest's mocking functionality](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) are unsuccessful. The Jest examples seem to assume that I'm mocking a module I have in the project. From the documentation I'm also unclear how to mock a specific function in a module.

Neither of these are working:

```js
    jest.mock('Yelp.searchBusiness', () => {
      return jest.fn(() => [{<stubbed_json>}])
    })
```

or

```js
    jest.mock('Yelp', () => {
      return jest.fn(() => [{<stubbed_json>}])
    })
```

I'm currently using `sinon` but would like to use just Jest. This Sinon approach works:

```js
    var chai = require('chai')
    var should = chai.should()
    var agent = require('supertest').agent(require('../../app'))

    const Yelp = require('node-yelp-api-v3')

    var sinon = require('sinon')
    var sandbox

    describe('router', function(){
      beforeEach(function(){
        sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()
        stub = sandbox.stub(Yelp.prototype, 'searchBusiness')
      })

      afterEach(function(){
        sandbox.restore()
      })

      it ('should render index at /', (done) => {
        /* this get invokes Yelp.searchBusiness */
        agent
          .get('/')
          .end(function(err, res) {
            res.status.should.equal(200)
            res.text.should.contain('open_gyro_outline_500.jpeg')

            done()
          })
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mocking external modules is explained [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules).

> If the module you are mocking is a Node module (e.g.: `lodash`), the mock should be placed in the `__mocks__` directory adjacent to `node_modules` (unless you configured roots to point to a folder other than the project root) and will be automatically mocked. There's no need to explicitly call `jest.mock('module_name')`.

For your exact case this would mean you need to create a folder `__mocks__` with a file `node-yelp-api-v3.js` in it. In that file you create a mock object from the original module using [`genMockFromModule`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestgenmockfrommodulemodulename) and override the method you want to mock.

```
// __mocks__/node-yelp-api-v3.js

const yelp = jest.genMockFromModule('node-yelp-api-v3')

function searchBusiness() {
    return [{<stubbed_json>}]
}

yelp.searchBusiness = searchBusiness

module.exports = yelp
```

Additionally you could also wrap the `searchBusiness` in `jest.fn` if you want to call assertions like `searchBusiness.mock.calls.length` for this method later.

Comment: Thanks @brass monkey. You should raise a PR in the Jest docs

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this:

```
jest.mock('Yelp', () => ({
    searchBusiness: jest.fn(() => [{<stubbed_json>}])
})
```

And then you'll be able to call things like expect(Yelp.searchBusiness).toHaveBeenCalled() etc.