# Jest: How to correctly mock a node module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I want to mock the node_module 'React Native Keychain' in React Native with Jest.

Following the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) I created a folder called `__mocks__` and created a file called `react-native-keychain.js` in it.

Here is the code within the file:

```
export default jest.mock("react-native-keychain", () => {
  const token = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  const credentials = {
    username: "session",
    password: token
  };
  return {
    setGenericPassword: jest.fn(
      (username, password) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true)) // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    ),
    getGenericPassword: jest.fn(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(credentials))), // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    resetGenericPassword: jest.fn(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true))) // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  };
});
```

I then wrote my tests for the functions that use this library:

```
import * as keyChainFunctions from "react-native-keychain";
import { setToken, getToken, clearToken } from "./secureStorage";

const token = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    describe("set token", () => {
      it("saves the token in the keychain", () => {
        expect.assertions(1);
        return setToken(token).then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(keyChainFunctions);
          expect(keyChainFunctions.setGenericPassword).toHaveBeenCalledWith("session", token);
        });
      });
    });
```

The problem is, that the test fails. I get the error message:

```
 FAIL  app/api/secureStorage/secureStorage.test.js
  set token
    ✕ saves the token in the keychain (42ms)

  ● set token › saves the token in the keychain

    expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalledWith()

    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received: undefined

      10 |       console.log(res);
      11 |       console.log(keyChainFunctions);
    > 12 |       expect(keyChainFunctions.setGenericPassword).toHaveBeenCalledWith("session", token);
         |                                                    ^
      13 |     });
      14 |   });
      15 | });

      at app/api/secureStorage/secureStorage.test.js:12:52
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
      at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
      at flush (node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
 ● set token › saves the token in the keychain

    expect.assertions(1)

    Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.

       6 | describe("set token", () => {
       7 |   it("saves the token in the keychain", () => {
    >  8 |     expect.assertions(1);
         |            ^
       9 |     return setToken(token).then(res => {
      10 |       console.log(res);
      11 |       console.log(keyChainFunctions);

      at Object.<anonymous> (app/api/secureStorage/secureStorage.test.js:8:12)
```

And the `console.log()` yield:

```
console.log app/api/secureStorage/secureStorage.test.js:10
    true

  console.log app/api/secureStorage/secureStorage.test.js:11
    { default:
       { addMatchers: [Function: addMatchers],

         advanceTimersByTime: [Function: advanceTimersByTime],
         autoMockOff: [Function: disableAutomock],
         autoMockOn: [Function: enableAutomock],
         clearAllMocks: [Function: clearAllMocks],
         clearAllTimers: [Function: clearAllTimers],
         deepUnmock: [Function: deepUnmock],
         disableAutomock: [Function: disableAutomock],
         doMock: [Function: mock],
         dontMock: [Function: unmock],
         enableAutomock: [Function: enableAutomock],
         fn: [Function: bound fn],
         genMockFromModule: [Function: genMockFromModule],
         isMockFunction: [Function: isMockFunction],
         mock: [Function: mock],
         requireActual: [Function: bound requireModule],
         requireMock: [Function: bound requireMock],
         resetAllMocks: [Function: resetAllMocks],
         resetModuleRegistry: [Function: resetModules],
         resetModules: [Function: resetModules],
         restoreAllMocks: [Function: restoreAllMocks],
         retryTimes: [Function: retryTimes],
         runAllImmediates: [Function: runAllImmediates],
         runAllTicks: [Function: runAllTicks],
         runAllTimers: [Function: runAllTimers],
         runOnlyPendingTimers: [Function: runOnlyPendingTimers],
         runTimersToTime: [Function: runTimersToTime],
         setMock: [Function: setMock],
         setTimeout: [Function: setTimeout],
         spyOn: [Function: bound spyOn],
         unmock: [Function: unmock],
         useFakeTimers: [Function: useFakeTimers],
         useRealTimers: [Function: useRealTimers] } }
```

What this tells me:
 1. Either the mock works (because true is returned correctly) or the actual `setGenericPassword` function from React Native Keychain is being called.
 2. For some reason, `keychainfunctions` is defined, but as the `jest.mock` object instead of the three mocked functions.

It feels like 1 and 2 contradict each other, if the mock works.
What am I doing wrong? Why does this mock not work? How can these weird `console.log()`s and failed tests be explained?

[Bamse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2890316/bamse) suggested in the comments to just export objects. This workaround works. I would still be interested how to correctly do it / what I did wrong.

```
const token = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
const credentials = {
  username: "session",
  password: token
};

export const setGenericPassword = jest.fn(
  (username, password) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true)) // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
);

export const getGenericPassword = jest.fn(
  () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(credentials)) // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
);

export const resetGenericPassword = jest.fn(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true))); // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

Comment: This answer also might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617362/how-to-mock-an-external-modules-function-with-jest#53022533

Comment: If you just want a return value, you could simply [bypass](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/bypassing-module-mocks)  the module using `jest.mock(module);` `import module from 'module';` `module.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve('response'));`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try to use [jest.createMockFromModule](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestcreatemockfrommodulemodulename) in your test and mock only the method you need. (previously in Jest versions prior to 26 called genMockFromModule)

Hope it helps

Comment: Bamse doesn't like mocking, but helps anyway. Lycklig den som har en sådan vän. :-)

Comment: I think your mocking would also work if  in `__mocks__/react-native-keychain.js` you export an object with the methods you want. Currently you are exporting a `jest` mock. 
Visibleman you made me smile this morning and made me think about my old comic books.

Comment: I tried using it like this: `const keyChainFunctions = jest.genMockFromModule("react-native-keychain").default;` but it also threw the same error.

Comment: You are correct. Just exporting plain objects works. I added it in the question.

Comment: It says a function when called will return `undefined`. So my mocked function just keeps returning `undefined` no matter what. I've already pulled half my hair out trying to fix this. The only thing that really works for me is this: `jest.mock('module', () => ({ myfunc: () => returnValue }));`

Comment: I want to test what happens when a function in a module returns a specific value. How do I ensure the mocked function returns that value?

Comment: Can you explain how to use this with an example I have no idea still